# How can I send stream with a specific position through wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming

My problem is that when the client call a method on the server to get a stream with in a specific position, the stream come with a position = 0 every time.

what can I do?

Server method:

```
public Stream SearchTorrent(int TorrentID, int Position)
        {
            string FilePatch = ClientBusinessLogic.MyTorrents().Where((MyTorrent1) => MyTorrent1.TorrentID == TorrentID).ToList().First().Patch;
            Stream File = new FileStream(FilePatch, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            File.Position = Position;
            return File;
        }
```

Client method:

```
Stream SeederFile = this.SeederInterface.SearchTorrent(TorrentID, Part.From);
```

Part.From value is not 0. 
But the stream that returns come back with position vlaue 0.

Comment: Show your work  in here.. People can't read your mind.

Comment: @Soner Gönül I edited my client server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Stream` returned from your server method is not returned by reference to the client. That is: they don't get your stream.

What they get is your content (starting at `Position`) streamed to them, so they get a stream starting at 0, with the tail end of the data from your original stream.

Basically: you can't return a reference to a stream. You get a copy of the contents.

What are you actually attempting to do?

Update: If you want to return a section of the file, you can use `byte[]`. This is basically what's going over the wire anyway. The downside of this approach is that you have to read the block into memory on the server.

So, instead, as an optimisation, you can still return `Stream`. This stream can wrap the portion of the file that you're returning. Note that it will always start at position zero.

Comment: The client need to download the stream from a specific position to a specific position. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Probably expose another method on server, that will return the only part you need?

Comment: as byte[] ? is this the only way?

Comment: If you think about it, what's going over the wire is already `byte[]`.